# Opening files without extensions fails in Photos

Tags: photos

when trying to open files without extensions (e.g .jpg), Photos fails to open them with the error message "Photos does not support the format of ".

This happens even though the thumbnailer creates correct thumbnails, and clicking on the file properties shows the correct file type, which indicates to me that the MIME type of the file is being correctly recognized.

So, does Photos not support opening files based on MIME types? Or am I doing something wrong? Is there some setting I can change to support this?

Comment: For anyone looking, the bug report can be found here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-photos/+bug/1535132

Answer (score 1):

The same happens on my laptop.I think this is an issue with pantheon-photos which is caused by it checking by the file extension (not mime type) and there is nothing we can do about it except creating an issue at https://launchpad.net/pantheon-photos

Comment: I'll open an issue and check the source to see if I can I already think of a fix.